# Path Finding in a Graph with A*

Tags: java, graph, path, shortest-path, a-star

I am attempting to build a Path Finding application to find the shortest path between two nodes in a Graph. I have chosen to use A* over Dijkstra.

Nodes are stored as objects with an adjacency list (Stored as an ArrayList of Nodes) in each node.

Sometimes the program is working as it should (However this is very rare). It also can't handle cases where the shortest path does not exist (Edges are randomly generated so there is not always a path)

```
    makeG(n, p);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Graph Successfully Created"); 
    System.out.print("Press 1 to View, Press 2 to Continue: "); 

    char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

    switch (choice) {
        case '1':  
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {

                System.out.println("X: "+myGraph.get(i).x+" Y: "+myGraph.get(i).y+" Z: "+myGraph.get(i).z);
                for(Node object: myGraph.get(i).edgeTo){
                    System.out.print(object.nID+"  ");
                }

                System.out.println();
    }
                 break;
        case '2': default: 
                 break;
   }        

    paths();

}


public static void makeG(int n, double p){
    Random r=new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        double x = 0 + (100 - 0) * r.nextDouble();
        double y = 0 + (100 - 0) * r.nextDouble();
        double z = 0 + (100 - 0) * r.nextDouble();

        myGraph.add(new Node(i, x, y, z));
    }

    for (int c = 0; c<n; c++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            if (!(c == j)){        //A node cannot have an edge to itself
                if (hasEdge()){
                    myGraph.get(c).edgeTo.add(myGraph.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public static boolean hasEdge(){
    boolean e = false;

    if( Math.random() < p){
        e = true;
    }

    return e;
}

public static void paths(){

    //ENTERING OF NODES WITH VALIDATION
    Node q = null, r = null;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Node ID of Start Node: ");

    if(!sc.hasNextInt()) { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid - Try Again"); 
        System.out.println();
        paths();
    } 

    int s = sc.nextInt();

    boolean hasS = false, hasF = false;

    for(Node object: myGraph){
        if(object.nID == s){
            hasS = true;
            q = object;
        }
    }

    if (!hasS){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid - NODE does not exist- Try Again"); 
        System.out.println();
        paths();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter Node ID of End Node: ");

    if(!sc.hasNextInt()) { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid - Try Again"); 
        System.out.println();
        paths();
    } 

    int f = sc.nextInt();

    for(Node object: myGraph){
        if(object.nID == f){
            hasF = true;
            r = object;
        }
    }

    if (!hasF){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid - NODE does not exist- Try Again"); 
        System.out.println();
        paths();
    }

    pathFind(q, r);       

}
```

THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC CODE - A* Pathfinding which takes as an input 2 nodes which exist in the graph. Please note that this graph is based on Euclidean Distance and method getCost will return the distance between 2 nodes.

```
public static void pathFind(Node q, Node r){
    ArrayList<Node> evaluated = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Node> tentative = new ArrayList<>();
    Node[] cameFrom = new Node[myGraph.size()];

    Node curr = null;
    double temp = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for(Node ob: cameFrom){
        ob = null;
    }

    double gScore[] = new double[myGraph.size()];
    double fScore[] = new double[myGraph.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i<myGraph.size(); i++){
        gScore[i] = Double.MAX_VALUE - 1;
        fScore[i] = Double.MAX_VALUE - 1;
    }

    gScore[q.nID] = 0;
    fScore[q.nID] = gScore[q.nID] + getCost(q, r);

    tentative.add(q);            //First checks around Start Node

    while (!tentative.isEmpty()){

        for(int i = 0; i < fScore.length; i++){
            if(fScore[i] < temp){
                curr = myGraph.get(i);
                temp = fScore[i];
                System.out.println("Curr is "+curr.nID);
                System.out.println("FScore["+i+"] = "+fScore[i]+" Temp = "+temp);
            }
        }



        if (curr == r){
            reconstruct(cameFrom, r);
            break;
        }

        tentative.remove(curr);
        evaluated.add(curr);


        for(Node object: curr.edgeTo){
            double tgScore;     

            if(evaluated.contains(object)){

                System.out.print("Contains node "+object.nID);

            } else {

                System.out.print("Doesn't Contain node "+object.nID);

                tgScore = gScore[curr.nID] + getCost(curr, object);

                System.out.println(tentative.toString());

                if (!tentative.contains(object) || tgScore < gScore[object.nID]){
                    cameFrom[object.nID] = curr;
                    gScore[object.nID] = tgScore;
                    fScore[object.nID] = gScore[object.nID] + getCost(object, r);

                    if(!tentative.contains(object)){
                        tentative.add(object);
                        System.out.println(tentative.toString());
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }



}

public static double getCost(Node dest, Node st){

    double dist = 0.00;

        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dest.x - st.x), 2)+ Math.pow((dest.y - st.y), 2)+ Math.pow((dest.z - st.z), 2));

    return dist;
}

public static void reconstruct(Node[] cf, Node curr){   
     for(Node ob: cf){
         if (ob != null){
            System.out.print(ob.nID + " > "); 
         }

     }
}
}
```

I have followed pseudocode Mostly that available on Wikipedia, however this is my first time using A* for pathfinding. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug your code without any example input and output, or you specifying what is going wrong, but here's one problem:

As the wikipedia psuedocode says, on each iteration through the while loop, you want to pick the node with the lowest F-score to expand. Right now, that's not what you're doing. Instead, you are choosing the first node with a score lower than temp. This might not be the lowest. An even bigger problem is that, since you're setting temp equal to the F-score of the node you expand, it is going to keep getting lower. At some point, it may well be below the F-scores of all of the remaining nodes, because there is no guarantee in A* that your paths aren't going to be worse than anticipated.

Comment: Thank You! You are absolutely right, these logical errors are by far the hardest to debug. 
It is now working after changing the while loop to loop through 'Tentative' not all fScores, and setting temp to MAXVALUE at the beginning of each loop.